# restrict forwarding existing email in office 365

Tags: security, exchange, microsoft-office-365

Multiple users were given permission to read a mailbox folder in exchange online. However they should not be able to forward / print / copy / paste those emails, basically the function of Azure Rights Management. Is there a way to do this? If not is there a workaround?

Azure Rights Management policies cannot be applied to existing mails or folders.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. No.
If they can read it, then they can copy/paste do anything they want with it. 
Even Azure rights management isn't fool proof - take a screenshot for example and email that.

Comment: Then how can I secure my information? Any suggestions? Enroll their devices in MDM and enforce policy as the only way? That may not be feasible under all circumstances...

Comment: You can't. As I wrote above, if I can see it, I can copy it.